# Accessing a viewcontroller's parent's title

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I need to determine what a parents title was to display the correct content in my app.  Using the title of the current viewcontroller doesn't work because it isn't unique.  For example, there are 2 text books in my app, Book 1 and Book 2.  Each book has a Lesson 1.  If I only access the title of the viewcontroller that I'm on, Lesson 1 will show the same content for both Lesson 1's.  I need to be able to access the parent title of Lesson 1 to show the correct content.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Share your code for better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Lesson 1 can hold a reference to it's parent book and then access the book's "title" property

Something like this:

```
Lesson *lesson1 = [[Lesson alloc] initWithParentBook:book];
```

and then access the title using the `book.title` property

Comment: How do I get to this point?  Currently to determine which content I should show I'm using this code.

`self.navigationItem.title rangeOfString:@"Lesson 1"`


I've tried

`self.presentedViewController.title`

But that doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't have classes to represent Lessons and Books? Can you please add some code you are using? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: Sure.
Sure. Everything is done in tables, when you click on a row it takes you to the next table, which is populated based on the title.   
`if([self.navigationItem.title rangeOfString:@"Words" ].location != NSNotFound)`  

Of course this falls apart when I have 2 titles that are the same.  

This code gets me close, but I can't quite figure out how to check the name of the title from it.  It does give me access to the title though  

`NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
            int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;`

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are using good design patterns. I suggest you ask yourself WHY you need the parent's title and if there would be a cleaner/safer way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll think on it and see what I can come up with.